# props automaticaly given as parameter

Tags: react-native

I would like to use a custom component and I need it to have the navigation props in order to navigate inside this component.

For now I'm passing navigation as a classic prop:

```html
<MyVideo videoSource={require('../Image/S01E01DB.mp4')}
         thumbnailSource={require('../Image/S01E01DB.mp4')}
         navigation={this.props.navigation}/>
```

But is it possible to always have him set as it was given as a prop?

I need that in order to simplify the usage of my prop.

Comment: The `navigation` prop is only set automatically on views that the navigator actually routes to, as far as I'm aware.

Comment: Can i make my nested component heir from the containing component ? (they are both in the stackNavigator list)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As said in the comments section by @jonrsharpe, the `navigation` props is only automatically given to routes declared with `createStackNavigator` or the others `react-navigation`navigators`

There's a tool you can use from `react-navigation` to connect any component to your parent navigator:

```
import { withNavigation } from 'react-navigation';

class MyBackButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <Button title="Back" onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.goBack() }} />;
  }
}
// withNavigation returns a component that wraps MyBackButton and passes in the
// navigation prop
export default withNavigation(MyBackButton);
```

In case of nested navigators, the `withNavigation` function will get the closest parent of your component.

You will find more informations on [this link](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/with-navigation.html)